# How to recover files in git deleted via command git clean -xdf without any commits

Tags: git, delete-file, data-recovery, file-recovery

I mistakenly have deleted all the files in the local repository via command `git clean -xdf` which did not commit for once since the creation. One of my codes was not working. It prompted me to use

```
git clean -xdf.
```

It removed all the files and my data. Is there any way to recover these?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clean+undo

Comment: @phd : thank you. git clean undo didn't help and for your earlier link to stackoverflow too

Answer (score 3):

It is sad but the answer is no you cannot recover it using `git`.

**Git does not know about them unless you committed them once.**

If you are lucky and use `git add` before deleting the files accidently then you can run this command to recover

```
git fsck | awk '{print $3}' | xargs git show | tee searchresults.log
```

You can also use recovery software to recover your deleted files

Software such as `photorec` or `Recuva`, you can find plenty of them.

Comment: thanks but i didn't do git add so can't use it :(

Comment: you have to try `photorec` or `Recuva` software for recovering your files

Comment: I tried using those. I am pretty aware of testdisk and photorec . Recuva is only for windows and mine is linux. I could get the files but those are all 0 bytes.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/248334/how-do-i-recover-now-zero-sized-files, as you can see here the `OP` is also highlighting the same answer for recovering the files having `0 bytes` size. You can try again with the help of these guide of `photorec` here https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step and  `testdisk`  here https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: Thanks I tried but no help. No worries!

Comment: that just saved 6 hours of work!!! thanks

Comment: Thanks! I had added the files before running clean. This really saved my effort.